# How do I update nested object state using useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, next.js, react-hooks

I am working on a Nextjs application with Typescript and would like to update a nested object state. Here is how the state looks like:

```js
const initialState ={
  userInfo: string | null
  isLoading: boolean,
  cursorState: boolean,
  companyProfile:{
    companyDescription?: string
    companyLogo?: string
    companyLogoPublicId?: string
    companyName?: string
    owner?: string
    _id?: string
  }
}
```

This is the reducer function:

```js
const Reducer = (state: initialStateAttributes, action: actionAttributes) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actionEnum.COMPANY_PROFILE_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        companyProfile: {
          ...state.companyProfile, 
          companyDescription: action.payload,
          companyLogo: action.payload,
          companyLogoPublicId: action.payload,
          companyName: action.payload,
          owner: action.payload,
          _id: action.payload
        }
      }
  }
}
```

And I am dispatching the action to update the state via API response data like this:

```js
const res = await axiosPrivate.get<axiosGetCompanyProfile>(
  `/getcompany`,
  {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `${data?.user.token}`
    }
  }
);
dispatch({
  type: actionEnum.COMPANY_PROFILE_DATA,
  payload: res?.data
});
```

I would like to update the entire state of `companyProfile` values on each update. I am not targeting one value at a time. I would like to change all values per update. The current way that I tried simply created each `companyProfile` value with all the payload on each of them.

How do I approach this?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue or problem with updating the state?

Comment: What I put up there is what I could come up with because I am only used to working with objects directly and not nested objects. So, I really dont know how to pass the data value from the api call to the companyProfile state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to update the entire state of companyProfile values on
> each update. I am not targeting one value at a time. I would like to
> change all values per update.

If I'm understanding this correctly it sounds like you would like to update the entire `state.companyProfile` value with the action payload value. Any state, and nested state, that is being updated should be shallow copied, and then overwrite the properties you want to update.

```js
const { data } = await axiosPrivate.get<axiosGetCompanyProfile>(
  "/getcompany",
  {
    withCredentials:  true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `${data?.user.token}`
    },
  },
);
dispatch({
  type: actionEnum.COMPANY_PROFILE_DATA,
  payload: data // <-- action payload is companyProfile data
});
```

```js
const reducer = (
  state: initialStateAttributes,
  action: actionAttributes
) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actionEnum.COMPANY_PROFILE_DATA:
      return {
        ...state, // <-- previous state shallow copied
        companyProfile: action.payload, // <-- set value
      };

    ...

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

If you want to "merge" new `companyProfile` data with existing `state.companyProfile` state then continue the "shallow copy, then overwrite" pattern.

```js
const reducer = (
  state: initialStateAttributes,
  action: actionAttributes
) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actionEnum.COMPANY_PROFILE_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        companyProfile: {
          ...state.companyProfile, // <-- preserve existing
          ...action.payload,       // <-- overwrite with new
        },
      };

    ...

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I actually tried this initially but got typescript error which I didnt pay attention to. But when I saw the same as your answer, I had to revert to it and paid attention to the typescript error which I fixed.

Comment: @kingNodejs What was the Typescript issue? Either way, welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Yea, typescript was complaining with the data type that was returned with action.payload. I simply use as {} and that took away the error.